# Clicking a button in host page from GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a simple host page for a GWT app with an input button like so:

```
<input id="Save" class="button" type="submit" name="Button" value="Save" />
```

Why does the following not work:

```
InputElement save = InputElement.as(RootPanel.get("Save").getElement());
save.click();
```

If I put a breakpoint I can see that the Save element was correctly assigned but click never seems to work. Any onclick handler for that button is never executed, and the form the button is in is never posted, although if I click on the button manually it works fine.

**EDIT:**
Please note that I already have an onclick defined, and as I mentioned that onclick is being called correctly when I manually click the submit button. I simply want to 'click' the submit button from GWT and have the same thing happen (onclick or form post).

**SOLUTION:**

Looks like the reason I was getting this error is I was using a modal popup panel, and no click events are registered while a modal popup is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="Save" class="button" type="submit" name="Button" value="Save"  onclick="alert('test')"/>
```

Well, onclick has been executed when click method has been called...

Edit :
 If you want to add click handler to this button, then  you should define it as button not input..

```
<button id="save" class="button" type="button"  name="save" />
```

And you can add click handler as below code;

```
 ButtonElement save = ButtonElement.as(RootPanel.get("save").getElement());
    final Button bt =  Button.wrap(save);
    bt.setText("save");
    bt.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            bt.setEnabled(false);

          }
    });
```

Comment: I already have a click handler defined (through javascript) on the button. I just want to programmatically 'click' the button.

Comment: programmatically , i have called click button of this button. I put another button , and I have called this button's click method at onclick method of the other button..

Comment: Thanks, looks like I had some strange issue with the test I was doing. I tried the same thing in a new project and it worked.

Comment: I'm curious if it is possible to bind a GWT click handler to the button element without wrapping it into GWT button?

Answer (score 1):

Folowing code is working fine. Probably you may submit your form like `onclick="{SUBMIT_SCRIPT}";`

```
<input id="Save" class="button" type="submit" onclick="alert('Hello');" name="Button" value="Save" />
```

.

```
InputElement save = InputElement.as(RootPanel.get("Save").getElement());
save.click();
```

**Scheduler Example;**

```
InputElement save = InputElement.as(RootPanel.get("Save").getElement());
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() { 
        save.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: I do have an onclick defined, and it executes perfectly when I click on the button with my mouse. The `save.click()` is what is not working, neither the onclick is being called nor is the form being posted.

Comment: I)n my example javascript alert is shown this means save.click works. Alternatively, you can try scheduler maybe it will works for you.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I had some strange issue with the test I was doing. I tried the same thing in a new project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason it was not working is because I was using a modal popup panel. No click events are registered when the modal popup panel is active (makes a lot of sense in hindsight).